# how add text editor in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my project i want to provide a text editor. i refer some sites.but still i have no correct idea for that.i try use textangular editor.i include

```
<script src="core/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="core/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script><script src="js/textAngular.js"></script>
```

### in controller

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",["ngRoute"],['textAngular']);
```

### html page

```
<div ng-model="htmlContent" name="demo-editor" </div>
```

but it gives me nothing. anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include few more scripts required for text angular:

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.5.0/textAngular-rangy.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.5.0/textAngular-sanitize.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.5.0/textAngular.min.js'></script>
```

That is not the right way of injecting dependencies. Change the below line

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",["ngRoute"],['textAngular']);
```

to

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute", "textAngular"]);
```

and then in your html template:

```
<div text-angular ng-model="htmlVariable"></div>
```

For more information refer to [textAngular documentation](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular)

Comment: when i put this single line of code var app = angular.module("myapp", ["ngRoute", "textAngular"]); nothing display except header and footer

Comment: You need to include all the required scripts as well.

Comment: yes..its successful. but i have a minor issue exist too. body of text editor is very small. and when we start typing on it that become misaligned. how can i fix that.?